How to get unit test code coverage of Android kotlin project?
I have a Andorid kotlin project. I want to get the code coverage of the unit test using some script as it needs to be included in CI/CD pipeline.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

You can do this with the Gradle JaCoCo (Java Code Coverage) Plugin
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html
Here's how I did it (sorry about Groovy, legacy project):
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
    ...
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.11"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {

    jacoco {
        includeNoLocationClasses = true
        excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.forEach { variant ->
        def nameTaskFragment = variant.name.capitalize(). // e.g. "Debug"

        def testTaskName = "test${nameTaskFragment}UnitTest"
        tasks.create(name: "${testTaskName}Coverage", type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "$testTaskName") {
            group = "Reporting"
            description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports for the ${variant.name} build."

            reports {
                xml.required = true
                csv.required = true
            }

            def excludes = [
                '**/R.class',
                '**/R$*.class',
                '**/BuildConfig.*',
                '**/Manifest*.*',
                '**/*Test*.*',
                'android/**/*.*',
                'androidx/**/*.*',
                // these classes are all generated
                'com/visualdx/android/databinding/**/*',
                'com/visualdx/android/generated/**/*',
                'com/visualdx/android/glide/**/*',
                'com/bumptech/**/*',
            ]
            classDirectories = fileTree(dir: variant.javaCompiler.destinationDir, excludes: excludes)

            sourceDirectories = files(["$project.projectDir/src/main/java"])

            executionData = files("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec")
        }

        tasks.named("$testTaskName") {
            finalizedBy "${testTaskName}Coverage"
        }
    }


Search for other JaCoCo answers on StackOverflow, there are plenty of examples.
